Guidance on running G*Power to calculate the sample size using Poisson Regression
I am working on a dissertation to determine if there is a difference in the number of specific disciplinary actions (5 count dependent variables) from before remote learning and after remote learning (categorical independent variable with 2 levels). I plan to use Poisson Regression for analysis. I think I know the tails, error, and power. The other inputs I am not sure. I am not sure what to input for exp, base rate, mean exposure, r² other x, and x parm π.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

More information was added

Base rate is the rate of the event happening at baseline. In your case that would probably be the rate of a given disciplinary action before remote learning (you need to only consider one dependent variable at a time here).
Exp(B1) is basically your effect size. It refers to the relative increase of the event rate over the base event rate exp(β0) when your predictor increases by one unit. For instance, if you believe after remote learning the disciplinary action increases by 10 % relative to baseline, this number would be 1.10.
Mean exposure is your time unit (during which your event are counted, probably 1 for you because you have two time points and you have counted the events within each).
r² other x is the variance in your outcome you expect other predictors to explain (0 if you have no other predictors than your before-after variable).
x parm π refers to the sampling ratio of your outcome. For instance, if you have equal number of disciplinary action cases sampled before and after remote learning, this input would be 0.5.
This is actually pretty clearly explained in the G*power manual (pp. 75-77 in the 3.1 version). This answer is probably also useful.

Thank you so much! I did read the manual but your explanation was much easier to understand. I appreciate your feedback.

@Sointu to calculate the base rate would I divide the mean number of infractions by the mean exposure?

This depends on how your data is collected. If you observed, say, 100 events before remote learning, and observed an infraction at 30 of those, this number would be 0.30. If, however, you have counts of infractions from a given number of days, this number would be the average number of infractions per day (before remote learning). Admittedly I'm a bit shaky on this step, so try to confirm this from another source.

Thank you so much. With your answer and an answer from a separate source I think it would actually be the average. You have been a tremendous help!

I'm glad I could help!
